# How do I display the entire req object from within a NodeJS / Express app?

Tags: javascript, node.js

What is the wrong w/this code?
I'm trying to display the request object from within a NodeJS app that uses Express.

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(req));
});

app.listen(3000);
```

I get the following error.

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    --> starting at object with constructor 'Socket'
    |     property 'parser' -> object with constructor 'HTTPParser'
    --- property 'socket' closes the circle
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/user/Desktop/test/app.js:8:19
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/user/Desktop/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at next (/Users/user/Desktop/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/Users/user/Desktop/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/user/Desktop/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
    at /Users/user/Desktop/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
    at Function.process_params (/Users/user/Desktop/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
    at next (/Users/user/Desktop/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
    at jsonParser (/Users/user/Desktop/test/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:110:7)
```

Comment: whats the output?

Comment: Thanks, just added it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> JSON doesn't accept circular objects - objects which reference
>   themselves. JSON.stringify() will throw an error if it comes across
>   one of these.

Just try to `console.log(req);` and you will get the correct expected output.

Comment: Thank you ... this didn't work earlier so there must have been a problem w/my config. But it works now.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `JSON.stringify()` and it will log.

Answer (score 1):

For human-readable output, you'd want [`util.inspect`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options); it has nice options for increased readability too:

```
console.log(
  util.inspect(req, {
    depth: 5,
    colors: true,
  }),
);
```